# How to view / monitor packets (incoming/outgoing) of AWS Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-vpn, aws-site-to-site

I want to monitor not just the metrics from my Site-to-Site VPN via CloudWatch, I ether want to see the whole incoming and outgoing traffic with source and destination addresses and packet types i.e. 1.2.3.4 => 12.20.12.1 ICMP (Port 123)

In Client VPN there is a possibility, but not in Site-to-Site VPN.

Comment: If the VPC flow logs are not enough, you can try to create a NAT instance to another VPN enforce the route with the VPC route. Then you could dump the traffic in the NAT instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/monitoring-cloudwatch-vpn.html#metrics-dimensions-vpn).

Only the following metrics are currently available:

1. `TunnelState` - Fractional value between 0 and 1
2. `TunnelDataIn` - Bytes
3. `TunnelDataOut` - Bytes